# How do you prune an object to its base object in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, security, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider following method:

```
public PrintObjectHierarchy(object o)
{
   Console.WriteLine(o.GetType.FullName);

   object baseObject = PruneObjectToItsBaseObject(o);
   if(!baseObject.GetType().Equals(typeof(object)))
       PrintObjectHierarchy(baseObject);
   else Console.WriteLine("System.Object");
}
```

For example if I wrote:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    PrintObjectHierarchy(f1);
  }
}
```

Then it should print for me:

```
MyNamespace.Form1
System.Windows.Form
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl
/*and so so till...*/
System.Object
```

But unforunately, even if I CAST object to its BaseType, "C# Polymorphism" just will limit its **VIEW** to the base type and does not return a **REAL** reference from a **REAL** base object to me! Let's describe it by an example; if I have

```
class Person {
public string Name;
public string LastName;
}
class President : Person {
public string password;
}

main(){
President pr = new President() {Name="John"; LastName="Smith"; password="js123" };
Person p = (Person)pr;
SendToAirportSystemAcrossInternet(p);
}
```

While we think that *p* is a *Person* but it's not! it's the *President* and *p* is just a view from it, so the president's password will travel across the Internet!

Any idea about how to prune or slice an object to it's base to creating a real base object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you're serialising your object somehow to transport it. Why don't you just prevent serialisation of the password field?

Comment: No, the president example is just an example. I really want to prune an object to it's base and pass it to an underlying recursive function which does something with object and do it again until rich a System.Object.

Comment: @YasserZamani: You can't do this. Imagine if you had an abstract class somewhere in the hierarchy - it would be a disaster. What are you *actually* trying to do with the object? You may well want to pass the object reference *and the Type to consider it as* to the method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see why you should worry about this. Any object can be *treated* as a `System.Object` due to inheritance. Why exactly does it matter that it isn't an instance of `System.Object`?

Comment: @AlexanderR , I mean the last step will return a System.Object which is null for example. Suppose you prune a tree until nothing remain from it :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'll skip abstract class in coding e.g. if(o.GetType().IsNotAbstract) Prune(o); so it does not mean that C# should not prune an object. Also, I don't want to send Type as parameter while I need object properties values. The request is simple: I need a real Person object from President.

Comment: @YasserZamani: The request is far from simple. The request may not even make sense - a set of fields which is valid *when the actual type is a subclass* may not be valid for the base type on its own. Whatever workaround you may conjure up, this is not something that either .NET or C# support natively, and personally I'm glad of that.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's solution works; another similar approach would be to write an "copy constructor" and create a new person that way.

So, your person class becomes:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(Person p)
    {
        this.name = p.name;
        this.lastName = p.lastName
    }

    public string name;
    public string lastName;
}
```

And you can create a person from a president like this:

```
President pres = new President() { name = "abc", lastName = "def", password = "kittens" };
Person p = new Person(pres);
```

This creates a person from a president but there is no way to get back to the president, and no way to get the password. If you create a person this was and cast to a president you will get an `InvalidCastException`, which I think is what you want.

Comment: the method should work on any object not just my defined object so it may does not implement "copy constructor" or may it's enough complicated object to implementing a "copy constructor" for it!

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite obvious what you're trying to achieve, but as you're interested in your object's inheritance hierarchy you'll most likely want to deal with instances of `System.Type`. Here's a working version of the first method you posted which might give you a hint on how to proceed from there:

```
static void PrintObjectHierarchy(object o)
{
    Type t = o.GetType();
    while (t != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.FullName);
        t = t.BaseType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I knew it's possible via [CODE]System.Type[/CODE] but in general I'm interested in why pruning an object to it's base type is an odd thing for people! e.g. at work I'm an instance of worker class but at family weekend I'm not worker longer. I think we should can prune an object like this, am I wrong?

Comment: @YasserZamani: You're wrong in that you *can't* do it (if you think you can, you should be able to *show* that you can, at which point you don't need to ask this question). If you're asking an object to change its behaviour to that of a different type, you should be creating a completely separate object in a way those types explicitly support. There's no "one size fits all" solution here. Just because you think there should be doesn't magically bring it into existence.

Comment: @JonSkeet: No, not every different type but it's underlying inherited type which we know supports a subset of methods and properties. I meant, at work I'm *class worker : person {}* but at family weekend I'm *class person {}* so when I go to weekend trip with my family, the system should *prune* me from *worker* class to it's underlying class, *person*. That's all!

Comment: @YasserZamani: You'd have to give a concrete example of *actual code* where this would be appropriate. It would normally just indicate that you ought to expose different interfaces to the same underlying data. Just because you can design poor type hierarchies doesn't suggest that your "pruning" idea is a good one. It's not.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't do what you want. You should redesign so that you don't have this requirement.

As I noted in comments, it may be that a set of fields in a base class is valid when the execution-time type is a derived class, but is invalid for an instance of just that class. Additionally, there may be all kinds of other safeguards which simply become invalid when an object is viewed in this way. For example, the base class may hold a reference to a collection of values, with the derived class expected to validate the values added to that collection. When the object is "pruned", that validation would be removed, but with a reference to the same collection as before:

```
// EvenNumbersOnlyCollection rejects odd numbers
EvenNumberCollection derived = new EvenNumbersOnlyCollection();
NumberCollection pruned = Prune<NumberCollection>(derived);
pruned.Add(5);

// This would return 5 - the invariant is broken!
int shouldBeEven = derived.First();
```

It's not clear *why* you think that this pruning would be a good idea, but you should try to achieve your wider goal in some other way.

Comment: Current design allows bypassing validation too: class NC { List<byte> l; public void Add(byte b) { l.Add(b) } }; class ENC : NC { public new Add(byte b) { if(b%2==0)base.Add(b); else throw new Exception(); } }; main() { ENC enc = new ENC(); ((NC)enc).Add(5); }; //what happens here?

Comment: @YasserZamani: You've broken the design by making `Add` non-virtual. It would normally be virtual, *overridden* in `ENC`. That's how the validation would be enforced. Obviously you can design code badly - but the point is that *well-written* code shouldn't be vulnerable to the sort of pruning you're suggesting.

Comment: I think making it *virtual* does not make any difference and validation can be bypassed. Also, we can bypass validation via reflection. so, providing *prune* ability does not violence current design of C# in bypassing validation field.

Comment: @YasserZamani: Making it virtual (and overriding in ENC) *absolutely* makes a difference. Try it! It means that even if you cast to NC, it'll still be `ENC.Add` which is called. You can only bypass validation via reflection with an appropriate trust level - and that's outside the scope of C#. (Heck, you could *probably* hack this up using reflection in many cases - that doesn't mean you *should*.) **Change your design so you don't need this.**

Comment: I can solve this security issue if it's the reason of not providing prune ability: The *Prune* method can be defined as *void Prune(ref object o)* which replaces the object reference with it's base object. so, the caller does not have access to it's previous object.

Comment: @YasserZamani: No, that doesn't resolve it at all. Just because that changes *one* variable doesn't mean there isn't another copy of the reference somewhere. I think I'm done with this question now, I'm afraid - I've given the best advice I can; if you want to ignore it, that's your call, but me just repeating that it's a really bad idea isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: Anyway, I think my *president class* example shows the security failure of C# well. Suppose in a complicated system you have a *p* which have been passed to you and you think it's a *person* while it's a *president* behind of a mask which can be hacked by someones. This is a bad idea not mine!

Comment: @YasserZamani: No, that would be a failure on the part of whoever design the Person and President classes. C# doesn't completely stop you from writing bad code (like having public fields, as in your example) but it doesn't go out of its way to help you shoot yourself in the foot, as your "pruning" suggestion would.

Comment: I made them public just for writing short; Actually I'm not new to C# at all. I was MSFT C# MVP at 2011. Why people don't accept when I write *Person p = (Person)president* then I really want the president as a just a real person but C# is fooling us by just making a view from it! Anyway currently I migrated to Linux and I don't need C# longer but just saying MSFT has many problems!

Comment: @YasserZamani: People accept that that's what you want, but not that it would be a good idea. It's simply not how .NET works (and if you do any work in Java, you'll find that works the same way too). (Note that an appeal to authority in terms of being an MVP is unlikely to impress folks very much - they're more likely to judge your ability on what you write than credentials like that.)

Answer (score 0):

When an object is created in C# is casted always to its original type. Even if you're using it as a base object or an interface, the call p.GetType() will always return the original type.

If you need to create a new object and then you need want to prune to its base object, you need to create a new object of  type. For example:

```
public class ParentClass
{
  public Parent(int feature1)
  {
    mFeature1 = feature1;
  }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
  public ChildClass(int feature1, int feature2) : base(feature1)
  {
    mFeature2 = feature2;
  }
}

...
...
ChildClass cc = new ChildClass(10, 20);
ParentClass pc = (ParentClass)cc; // pc still is of type ChildClass
ParentClass ccAsParent = new ParentClass(cc.Feature1); //ccAsParent is of type ParentClass
...
...
```

Remember that you can only do this if the parent class is not **abstract**.

Comment: the method should work on any object not just my defined object!

Comment: Actually Suppose I have been instantiated an object from a third party dll and I would like to apply my scenario on it.